# Exposing contents of multi-rich column in a custom webpart

Tags: web-part, rich-text

Scenario : Sharepoint 2010 foundation site with a custom ASPX page. 
The custom ASPX page has a webpart wherein I read the contents of a multi-richtext field from a list.

I want to know within the webpart which is best control to get exactly whatever is typed or pasted within multi-richtext field.

Currently I am using DIV and innerhtml (something like this)

dDivData.Innerhtml = oListItem["RichDataHolder"].ToString();

Problem I am facing is some of the images (either pasted from different location or uploaded to siteAssets library) and tables (like table with a header and 5 columns) do not get displayed.

I am thinking something is getting messed up because of "innerhtml". I tried with "Literal" and it has same problem too.

Can anyone suggest the best options? If it is required to have different approach also, please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this...

in the .ASPX (...or .ASCX if you're using a User Control) file:

```
<div><%=this._innerHtml%></div>
```

in the C# code-behind (.ASPX.CS or .ASCX.CS):

```
private string _innerHtml;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _innerHtml = oListItem["RichDataHolder"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this to get the formatted HTML value:

```
dDivData.Innerhtml = oListItem.GetFormattedValue("RichDataHolder").
```